# Не могу разобраться с поиском строки из файла

Tags: python, format

У меня имеется текстовый файл с следующим форматом данных в них:

```
Имя|почта|пароль
Имя|почта|пароль
```

n-ое количество таких строк в столбик
В данных "почта" имеются разные домены. Необходимо отсортировать разные почтовые домены в свои файлы (файлы создать я смог)

```
f = open(u'E:\\Screen.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8'
s = f.read()
for yandex in s:
yandex = s.find('@yandex.ru')
d = open(открываю файл для записи строки, если строка имеет почту "yandex"
d.write(yandex)
d.close()
```

Comment: Почитай о dataframe из библиотеки pandas. Это то, что тебе нужно

Comment: Комментарий в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений": непонятна конкретная проблема. Приведите код, сообщите, что конкретно не получается.

Comment: в коде куча проблем. 1. yandex сначала переменная для итерации по файлу, а в следующей строчке это уже вдруг число. 2. В файл ты записываешь число, а не строчку. 3. Ищешь @yandex.ru ты не в строчке, а во всем файле. 4. Не нужно для каждой строчки открывать и закрывать файл. Сначала раскидай строчки по разным переменным, а потом записывай. 4. Собираешься вручную проверять каждый домен?

Comment: Насчёт первых трёх вопросов - я ещё не до конца разбираюсь с переменными, восполняю пробелы в знаниях постоянно, а над четвертым, то у меня известны, какие домены в базе и по сути для каждого домена я пытался создать такой цикл, если есть возможность облегчить и сделать такой поиск независимый от количества разных доменов то я с радостью это изучу